# hide a ul when clicked on any li

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have filters which show data by month as per below snippet

I want to close/hide ul which has class "children" when clicked on any li of class "nowShowing". Please help in identifying the event as I tried below but still not work

```js
  $('.children').click(function() {
    children.hide();
  })
```

```html
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="parent active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="customfilters">Filter by Month</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="nowShowing"><a class="all" id="all2" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".June" class="June">June</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".July" class="July">July</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".August" class="August">August</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".September" class="September">September</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.closest` to hide

```
 $('.nowShowing').click(function(){
  $(this).closest('.children').hide();
});
$('.customfilters').click(function(){
  $('.children').show();
});
```

Demo :https://jsfiddle.net/gaq23jbL/6/

Comment: thanks for your help. it is working but again clicking on "Filter by Month" children menu should appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this like:

```
$('.nowShowing').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.children').hide();
});
```

Ex:

```js
$('.nowShowing').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".children").hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="parent active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="customfilters">Filter by Month</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="nowShowing"><a class="all" id="all2" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".June" class="June">June</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".July" class="July">July</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".August" class="August">August</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".September" class="September">September</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but how to show "children" menu again on "Filter by Month" click which has class "Parent"

Answer (score 0):

Use [.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
  $('.nowShowing').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".children").hide();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filters">
  <li class="parent active"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="customfilters">Filter by Month</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="nowShowing"><a class="all" id="all2" href="#" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".June" class="June">June</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".July" class="July">July</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".August" class="August">August</a></li>
      <li class="nowShowing"><a href="#" data-filter=".September" class="September">September</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could do this. Instead of accessing parent you could select `nowShowing` element.

```
$('.nowShowing').on('click', function(){
   $(this).parent().css('display','none');
 });
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/keqcqa5h/)